# Can minecraft pocket edition on an ipad connect to minecraft pc?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a laptop and someone wants to connect to my world through their iPad mini. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are different games with different feature sets.

As seen in the "Play it" section on the [unofficial wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_Wiki), the iOS version is the "Pocket Edition" and is different from the PC version.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't play regular Java Minecraft.

BUT you can play with [Minecraft Windows 10 Beta,](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/minecraft-windows-10-edition-beta/9nblggh2jhxj) however it is nearly same with phone edition, so it doesn't have some blocks which are available in PC.